# many, much, a lot of in Latin

Tags: vocabulary

Can the Latin word *multus* be used both for expressing greater amounts of both countable and uncountable nouns?

(in English there is many for countable, much for uncountable or the universal a lot of)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *multus* can be used for countable as well as uncountable things:

- **in the singular** it is used with uncountable things, especially abstract things like *multa cura*, *multus sermo*, etc., but also with substances like *multus sudor, multus sanguis*, *multum cibum*, and so on.

However, note that “much money” is *magna* or *grandis pecunia*, and likewise you have *maior* and *maxima pecunia*, and I believe the same applies to *aes alienum* (debt).

It is also worthwhile to mention that you can use the neutral *multum* with the genetive of the thing or substance (genetivus partitivus), e.g. *multum vini* “much wine”, *multum diei* “much of the day.” But this can only be used in the nominative and accusative, and even then not with prepositions that take the accusative.

- **in the plural** it is used with countable things, e.g. *multi libri, homines, timores, etc.* If combined with another adjective, they should be connected with *et*, like *multa et clara facinora* (many great deeds).